# Need a window exhaust fan with louvers that close automatically

Tags: ventilation

I currently put a box fan in a window as an exhaust fan when I need to ventilate a room in my house.  But when I turn the fan off, I need to remove the fan and close the window.  I'd like to have a system with louvers that automatically close when the fan shuts off so I don't need to worry about hot air or bugs coming in.  But I don't want a unit that requires any alterations to the window frame.  Is there such a thing?

Comment: Last bathroom fan I saw actually had "motorized" louvers, using a simple electro-thermic actuator (simple and cheap, as opposed to motor + position sensor).

Comment: See the [meta discussion](//meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plenty of manufacturers make [louvered fans](https://www.google.com/search?q=louvered%20fan&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) that only require air flow (or the lack of) to operate the louvers. If you don't want to screw the flange to the window frame, you can attach a smaller one to a plywood insert, cut to fit snugly inside the frame.

[image]

<sub>[source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TR3ZIW)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Whole-house fans are generally equipped with a motorized louver system.

Exhaust ducts (eg bathroom ventilation fans or clothes drier exhausts or kitchen exhausts) often have a seal of some sort which is simply blown out of the way while air is flowing, then closed by gravity.